# Jquery Classes are not removed on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Im creating a jquery plugin the output is similar to a reminder app
now my problem is whenever I mark all of it the classes will be placed which is correct but as soon as I try to unmark the tasks I marked only the 1st element has its classes removed any idea? here is my jquery code

```
//iterator for General Matters's todo 
$.fn.iteratethis = function() {
    this.find("li").each(function(index) {
        var roots = $(this);
        console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
        $(this).find(".tsk").on("click", function() {
            $(roots).not(document.getElementById("not-data")).addClass("strikeit hide");
            if ($(roots).hasClass('tmpReveal')) {
                $(roots).removeClass('tmpReveal strikeit hide');
            }
        });
    });
    return this;
}

//Shows finished Todo
$.fn.showme = function() {
    this.on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#task_list').find("li.hide").removeClass('hide').addClass('tmpReveal');
        } else {
            $('#task_list').find("li.tmpReveal").removeClass('tmpReveal').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
    return this;
}
$('#GeneralMattersLink').on("click", function() {
    $('#GeneralMatters').siblings().hide();
    $('#GeneralMatters').toggle("fast", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hide");
        //Modal for the New TODO
        $('#new_task').on("click", function() {
                $('#add_new_task').modal('show');
            })
            //Save button for the todo
        $('#addnewtodo').on("click", function() {
            var ai = $('#task_list').children("li").length;
            $('ul#task_list').prepend("<li class='list-group-item'><div class='tbl-r'> \n\n\
<div class='tbl-c'><div class='checkbox_round'><input type='checkbox' \n\n\
name='check[]' id=" + ai + " class='tsk' value=''/><label for=" + ai + "></label></div></div><div \n\n\
class='tbl-c'><p>" + $("#new_todo").val() + "</p></div></div></li>");

            $('#new_todo').val("");
            $(this).modal('hide');
            $('ul#task_list').iteratethis();
        });

        $('ul#task_list').iteratethis();
        $('#sfsh').showme();


    });
});
```

**MY HTML**

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <!-- Default panel contents -->
                            <div class="panel-heading bold">General Matters <span id="new_task" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                            <!-- List group -->
                            <ul id="task_list" class="list-group todopanel">
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**The modal**

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="add_new_task" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New Todo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!--form -->
                     <form id='winebeerForm' class="form-horizontal">
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <input type="text" name="new_todo" id="new_todo" class="form-control" placeholder="New Todo" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="addnewtodo" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" >Save</button>
                    <!--/ from -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

everything else works except for the unchecking part of a task

Comment: Binding click handler inside click handler is not cool.

Comment: maybe it happens because all the elements don't have all the classes `'tmpReveal strikeit hide'`

Comment: and why are you using $(roots). It's not equal to $(this), because roots is not equal to this, but it is equal to $(this). So you should use only roots not $(roots)

Comment: @AminJafari "*More than one class may be removed at a time, separated by a space*" https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: @Mike `$($($(this)))` works just the same as `$(this)`, so not the issue here.

Comment: @freedomn-m I know, but if all the classes are not available...

Comment: @AminJafari not clear what you're saying.  If *any* of the 3 classes are there, it will remove the one (or more) that is there.   Not "all".  The line before confirms .tmpReveal will be there, so this is removed and the other two may or may not be.

Comment: hi @Satpal what can I do then? also might that be the cause of my prob?

Comment: Hi Guys regarding the classes.. my classes are added on click.. I made sure that the classes are there via inspect element at google chrome and 1st element is ok I can uncheck and check it normally  but the next one the classes remains there even if I check or uncheck it. it wont remove the classes

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m I didn't know this :)

Comment: @KimOliveros this is frequently caused by using the same id (`$("#id")....`) across multiple elements - jquery will only affect the first as it's expecting only one.  Other causes are the event firing multiple times (eg toggle twice becomes no change) which can happen if you bind the event multiple times (eg binding inside another click event).  It's hard to see what the problem is in your code - you should try to create a minimal version that does the same (eg remove the modal, remove the dynamic html, until it does the same without these) You may find the issue yourself by doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all I would like to thank freedomn-m for the tips he/she gave me on how I might solve my issue and this is how I did it.. although Im not sure if this is the most efficient way

after I did it one by one I managed to make it work using 1 function the function name that I edited was `iteratethis`

the new code became like this

```
        $.fn.iteratethis = function () {
                this.find("li").not(document.getElementById("not-data")).each(function (index) {
                    index++;
                    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
                    $("#" + index).on("click", function () {
                     //newcode added
                    if (!($(this).is(":checked"))) {
                            $(this).parent().closest('li').removeClass("strikeit tmpReveal hide");
                        } else {
                            $(this).parent().closest('li').addClass("strikeit hide");
                        }
                    });

                });
                return this;
            }
```

I Added  an if statement that checks if that certain checkbox is currently checked then inside the checkbox I had it look for the parent then remove the class that I want to remove

and that's about it